# What's the word regarding hiring few employee of minority groups to achieve pseudo equality?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just suddenly forgot this word, and couldn't find anything relevant from Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for **tokenism**:

> Tokenism is the practice of making only a perfunctory or symbolic effort to be inclusive to members of minority groups, especially by recruiting a small number of people from underrepresented groups in order to give the appearance of racial or sexual equality within a workforce.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia: Tokenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenism)</sub>

Comment: "Tokenism" if the reason is a PR stunt. "Quotas" might be used once outsiders attempt to mandate something, even if there's no legal obligation (yet) that "one in ... must be ..." That would suggest we don't feel we have any other choice.